# Serial data into textboxes

Tags: c#, textbox, serial-port

I'm getting data in from serial and splitting it into different textboxes. This works, but after about 2 readings the program freezes with the error "IndexOutOfRange was unhandled on the `Set1(array[0])` or `Set2(array[1])` lines."

Here is my code, any help is much appreciated.

**code**

```
 private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string data_in = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
        char[] delimiter1 = new char[] { '*' };
        string[] info = data_in.Split(delimiter1, StringSplitOptions.None);

        this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler(delegate
        {
            //Set(array);
            Set1(info[0]);
            Set2(info[1]);
        }));
        Application.DoEvents();
    }

    private void Set(string[] strText)
    {
        tbFib.Text = strText[0];
    }

    private void Set1(string strText)
    {
        tbGravity.Text = strText;
    }

    private void Set2(string strText)
    {
        tbTemp.Text = strText;
    }
```

Comment: Well how many entries does `info` contain when you try to access the first or second item?

Comment: For sure there is not always a * in the data being received...

Comment: The data is being split into two textboxes.

Comment: From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx) it says that `serialport.ReadExisting()` doesn't have a timeout, which means it does not wait for data, it just reads what is there at that exact time. This leaves the possibility of you reading an empty buffer and when you split it you are left with an empty string. If `info` is a single element array with an empty string, when you try to index `info[1]` you get an error since you only have one element.

Answer (score 1):

The data coming in from `serialPort1.ReadExisting()` clearly doesn't contain a `*` in some (or all) cases. This would result in your call to `data_in.Split` returning a potentially empty array.

One obvious solution would be to check the length of `info` before trying to access the potentially non-existent locations in the array.